# How can I make the potentiometer longer and flip it around the x axis?

Tags: circuitikz

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages] \draw
  (5,0) to
  (5,3) to [V, v<=15<\volt>,  a = $V_{source}$] (-1,3) --
  (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [pR, l = $Load$, a = 50k$\Omega$] (3,0) -- (5,0)

;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The resistor marked in red box is what I want to achieve.

I have tried to use `rotate` and `yscale`, but both of them don't work for me. And how can I adjust the length of the resistor?

[image]

Comment: There is an example that does exactly that at page 53 of the (current) manual, under "resistive components customization"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As supplement to @marijn answer:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages,
    > = Straight Barb
                    ] 
\ctikzset{resistors/width=1.6, resistors/zigs=7}
\draw   (0,0) to [V=15<\volt>,  a = $V_{\mathrm{source}}$] ++ (-4,0) 
        -- ++ (0,-3)
        to [pR, a = Load, l = 50<\kilo\ohm>, mirror, name=R] ++ (4,0) 
        -- (0,0)
        ;
\draw[|<->, 
      transform canvas={yshift=0.5mm}] (R.north west) -- node[fill=white, inner sep=0pt] {$V_{\mathrm{th}}$} (R.wiper);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `wiper' (in 'wiper').

Comment: @kile, you may installed old `circuitikz` and `tikzpackage` package. I tested my MWE with circuitikz version 1.5.5 (2022/11/12) and have installed `tikz` version 3.1.9a` and works fine: no warnings, no errors.

Answer (score 4):

The longer resistor is described in the CircuiTikZ [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) on page 52:

> For the american style resistors, you can change the number of "zig-zags" by setting the key `resistors/zigs` (default value 3).

In the manual this sentence is followed by a code example which I repeated in the MWE below.

Switching the labels and annotations can be done using `l_` instead of `l` for a label below the element and `a^` instead of `a` for an annotation above the element. Putting the arrow on the other side can be done using the `mirror` key.

Note: since you load the `siunitx` option for `circuitikz` it would make sense to use this not only for Volt but also for kOhm, which improves the spacing a bit.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, longpot/.style = {pR, resistors/scale=0.75,
resistors/width=1.6, resistors/zigs=6}] \draw
  (5,0) to
  (5,3) to [V, v<=15<\volt>,  a = $V_{source}$] (-1,3) --
  (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [longpot, l_ = $Load$, a^ = \qty{50}{\kohm}, mirror] (3,0) -- (5,0)
 
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How can add the annotation  arrow and `V_{th}`? I mean `|<-50 k\ohm ->|` and `|<- V_{th} ->|`

Comment: @kile for that you should use plain Ti*k*Z commands, using the anchors provided by the components. In other words, that kind of annotation is not included in `circuitikz`, and you need to draw it "by hand". But that should arguably be another question...

Comment: @Marjin I got the following message when I was compiling your code.
`[4]
Runaway argument?
american voltages,longpot/.style = {pR, resistors/scale=0.75,resistor\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@picture was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par `

Comment: It's my my fault. I forgo to add `}` at the end. Sorry to disturb you.